# Predis Aysnc Doubts

Tags: yii, redis, predis

I was told that if I want to use predis-async, then I will use some kind of async web framework (probably built using https://github.com/reactphp/react). I am currently using Yii.

I was also told that

```
$client->getEventLoop()->run();
```

That line will start event loop which won't return after all connections to Redis are terminated and all callbacks are invoked. So that means that this line will be blocking for your code. Try to run following code (the simplest code illustrating Predis Async usage):

```
$client = new Predis\Async\Client('tcp://127.0.0.1:6379');
$client->set('test', 'value');

$client->getEventLoop()->run();
echo 'END';
```

END won't be probably displayed for a long time or maybe never, but for sure it will take more than the same operation using non-Async
Predis.

However, my own understanding is that existing PHP system should be able to use Predis Async right out of the box, as a lib. Which means existing PHP system does not need to be on ReactPHP. My idea of using predis async is similar to using mongodb asynchronous
commit. When PHP calls mongodb lib to commit a write operation, it is
asynchronous. Mongodb immediately returns the call rather than waiting for
the write happens first. In this case, mongodb doesn't requires
asynchronous php framework too.

Is it true that

> END won't be probably displayed for a long time or maybe never, but
>   for sure it will take more than the same operation using non-Async
>   Predis.